# How To Select Multiple Row With Same Column Condition

Tags: sql, oracle

How To Select Multiple Row With Same Column Condition?

```
Name    Plat
 Bob       1
 Kay       2
 Sih       3
```

I have these two parameters, Bob and Kay. So i need to retrieve Bob and Kay record. If Bob or Kay does not exist in table, return empty. If Bob and Kay exist in table show two records.

The sql below not work for me

```
Select * from table where Name = 'Bob' And Name = 'Kay'
```

Any help?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: db im using is Oracle

Comment: You seem to be missing some details. So, if only one of `Bob` or `Kay` exist you don't want any rows returned? What if there are multiple rows with either (both?), do you want all of the rows returned? Only one for each? If so, whats the requirement for which ones?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `exists` with `HAVING` condition aggregate function.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Name VARCHAR(5),
   Plat int
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Bob',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Kay',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Sih',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Sih',4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Bob1',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM T t1
WHERE exists(
  SELECT 1
  FROM T tt
  WHERE t1.Name in ('Bob','Sih')
  HAVING 
      SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Bob' THEN 1 END) > 0
  AND
      SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Sih' THEN 1 END) > 0
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e2fb/1/0)**:

```
| NAME | PLAT |
|------|------|
|  Bob |    1 |
|  Sih |    3 |
|  Sih |    4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes Bob and Kay are unique within the table

```
  Select * from table 
   where Name IN ('Bob', 'Kay') 
     and ( select count(*) from table where Name IN ('Bob', 'Kay')) = 2
```

Comment: Yes.  count(distinct Name) instead of count(*)

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from table where Name = 'Bob' OR Name = 'Kay'`

You want to select a row where the name = 'Bob' **OR** the name = 'Kay'. Remember the SQL is applied per row, so a name cannot equal both 'Bob' and 'Kay' at the same time.

Comment: Lets say if select * from table where Name = 'Bob' OR Name ='aaaaa'. aaaaa is not exist on the table. I want it return empty instead of Bob record

Answer (score 0):

I would use temporal tables to do that operation, something like this:

```
DECLARE @First NVARCHAR(50) = 'Bob';
DECLARE @Last NVARCHAR(50) = 'Kay';

SELECT *
INTO #TempSearch
FROM table
WHERE (Name = @First OR Name = @Last)

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    (SELECT COUNT(a.Name) FROM table AS a WHERE Name = @First) AS TotalByFirst,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.Name) FROM table AS b WHERE Name = @Last) AS TotalByLast
INTO #TempTotal
FROM #TempSearch

SELECT ts.*
FROM #TempTotal AS t, #TempSearch AS ts
WHERE t.Total = (t.TotalByFirst + t.TotalByLast)
AND t.TotalByFirst > 0 AND t.TotalByLast > 0

DROP TABLE #TempTotal
DROP TABLE #TempSearch
```